# Go send null in json

Tags: go

```
type JobTitles struct {
    Titles []string `json:"titles"`
}

chiefTitles := []string{"CEO", "CFO", null, "CMO"}

jsonOut := JobTitles{chiefTitles}
```

In the code above, I would like to be able to send *null* as one of the values in my json string array. However, the above will not compile and if I add double quotes to *null* it becomes a string not the value null.

How can I send *null* in my json response in GO?

[This](http://dennissuratna.com/marshalling-nullable-string-db-value-to-json-in-go/) article seems to help, but looks to be the inverse of my question..

Comment: In Go a `string` can't be `nil` (*not* `null`). Would `Titles []*string` work for you? (It would be a bit harder to initialize via a literal).

Comment: You can't use `null` because the value in Go is `nil` and you can't use if for a string, it would have to be a string pointer.

Comment: I changed the title. Im sorry for my ignorance -- no disrespect to the Go community! Can you show an example of how to initialize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to represent that type with the value 'null' it would have to be a pointer. The problem isn't that you can't use null but rather that a string can't have that value. Here is a quick example I made in the playground; https://play.golang.org/p/SXO5sBl2mR

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Test struct {
    A *string
    B *string
}

func main() {
        s := "Something"
        t := Test{A:&s, B:nil}
        b, err := json.Marshal(t)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

As DaveC mentioned using pointers makers the initilization a bit more cumbersome but you can use the same type of constructs I have above; declare a string, use the `&` that string in the composite literal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer @evanmcdonnal

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `*string` instead, and create a helper function to make it easier, something along the lines of:

```
func main() {
    chiefTitles := []*string{sP("CEO"), sP("CFO"), nil, sP("CMO")}

    b, _ := json.Marshal(JobTitles{chiefTitles})

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

type JobTitles struct {
    Titles []*string `json:"titles"`
}

func sP(s string) *string {
    return &s
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/8mE2Hug8Zb)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, this makes sense!